# System Formatter Failed While Erasing External Hard Drive Mac

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have been trying to erase my external Hard Drive "My Passport", however there was a problem and then the Hard Drive disappeared from the Desktop and could't be found. Only **Disk Utility** would see it but it would't mount it. I tried erasing it and partitioning it, however nothing helped and i'd always get this error: **"System Formatter Failed"**.

I found a few links that worked on previous version of OS X, eg. [Link 1](http://macintosnews.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-fix-file-system-formatter-failed.html), or [Link 2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1282849?tstart=0). None of those worked, I always would get the error message and could never mount the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that works on both OS 10.11 El Capitan and on OS 10.10 Yosemite is:

1. Open up Disk Utility
2. Select the actual drive, which is the lower part that will most likely be greyed out:
3. Then go to Erase
4. Select MAC OS EXTENDED (Journaled, Encrypted) It's important to select Encrypted
5. Then enter a password and wait.(It will run without a problem )
6. Then you can again erase and take the password down and use your drive again.