# Cannot format SSD to OS X Extended (Journaled) in order to restore

Tags: partition, ssd, restore, disk-format

yesterday my computer stayed awake during all night, when I woke up it stopped working. I got many errors, one that says for example that I don't have enough space in my computer even though that when I checked it said I have more than 75 GB available.
So  after everything failed I booted in Recovery Mode (Cmd+R) and started playing with it. Currently my state is that my SSD is formatted to exFat because I can format to any kind of filesystem except OS X Extended (Journaled). Also, I can only boot up in Recovery Mode, no OS at the moment.
Every time I try to to erase and format to OS X Extended (Journaled) with GUID Partition Map I get this error:

```
input/output error:
newfs_hfs: write (sector 149512): Invalid Argument

Mounting Disk:
Could not mount disk0s2 with name(null) after erase.
File system formatter failed.
Operation failed.
```

#### Technical info

MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2010 with SSD 240GB Kingston (SATA).

Comment: Journaled is optional. Can you try the erase again with straight HFS+. Also, you could try installing the OS to an external USB drive to ensure its not a failure of the ssd or connector.

Comment: Please boot into Internet Recovery or with USB-Stick and try to format from there. You might try a possible solution from here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194133/system-formatter-failed-while-erasing-external-hard-drive-mac

Answer (score 1):

If trying one more time to format HFS non journaled fails, you may want to use the erase and install steps from:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Hopefully it's not a hardware error and you can just fix this with a clean erase. Installing to an external dive may also help you determine if it's an issue with procedure or your installer vs the ssd.