# Remove unwanted 'system' files

Tags: macos, storage, file

Is there any way I can remove some of the 'system' files on my Mac. I understand that normally they shouldn't be touched, but I think most of mine are for old programs that are no longer installed. It's wasting so much space on my computer.
[image]

I have 41GB of system files, I'm sure a lot of these must be from old programs that are no longer installed.

Comment: Usually, that's a temporary situation. Do you have a backup and do you see any previous system folders at the root of Macintosh HD?

Comment: If this is macOS Sierra, then you cannot count on what you see under Storage from About This Mac because Sierra does not report the correct content types and values in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would be extremely hesitant to remove any system files on your Mac, especially since you're not even sure what many of them are. While it is possible to do what you want, I have seen many examples of people doing this and having unintended consequences.

If you're convinced that your system is taking a lot more space than necessary, then the best option to ensure you don't run into problems is to follow these steps:

1. Make a full Time Machine backup
2. Do an [erase of the drive to cleanly re-install just macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239526/5472)
3. Migrate across all the data etc you still want from your Time Machine backup

Comment: I'd go erase install as well if you can't find previous files. After making the full backup and committing to potentially erasing, at that point, it's less risky to try cleaning up duplicate system files. Something is clearly amiss - system should be 5 to 10 GB max on most 10.12 systems. This is 7x as big as expected.